# Sort in Excel on column with formula

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula

I've got a spreadsheet with these values:
[image]

Column D has format Number, 0 and is calculated by the formula =SUM((IF(VALUE(RIGHT(C3,2))<0,VALUE(RIGHT(C3,1)),VALUE(RIGHT(C3,2)))),0)

(Giving the numeric value of the paint)

What I want to do is sort the data by Column C alphabetically, then Column D numerically, so I get all the paint types grouped together in ascending numeric order.

If I sort by Column D, then Column C, it sorts the numeric Column D values correctly:
[image]

[image]

If I sort by Column C, then Column D, it sorts the numeric Column D values alphabetically:
[image]

[image]

I've no idea why the order of the sort columns affects the way they're sorted.

Comment: If you sort by two different things you get two different results.

Comment: You are sorting using column C, and the data is text. When treated as text, 10 comes before 2. So `MS-10` goes before `MS-2`

Comment: If you add another helper column for the first 2 letters and sort on the two helpers it'll do what you intend.

Comment: You could simplify your formula in column D to be: 
=RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-3)